# How do I get a list of table column names in big query using Go

Tags: go, google-bigquery

I can't seem to find a function in the bigquery golang API to get columns from a table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Table service to get a table meta info and then iterate table.Schema.Fields

You can also check some existing code using Google BigQuery API
https://github.com/viant/bgc/blob/master/dialect.go#L216

Answer (score 0):

You can either use type Schema [[1]](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/bigquery#Schema) or run a query to get them [[2]](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/bigquery#Query).

Here's the full documentation of Go language and BQ [[3]](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/bigquery) and how to use the client library [[4]](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries). Also, two repositories of Go lang and BQ [[5]](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/tree/1d559fe9b6287e030819171e8c0ec7b054841491/bigquery) [[6]](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-go/tree/master/bigquery). Maybe you can think of other ways by checking the documentation posted.